# When specifying OnDestroy of a base class, should the derived class call it explicitly?

Tags: angular

If I have a derived service class with no OnDestroy method, and the base class has one, will the base class' OnDestroy method be implicitly called when the derived class is destroyed?

```
export class DerivedService extends MyBaseClass {
   // ...
   // No OnDestroy method
}

export class MyBaseClass implements OnDestroy {
   OnDestroy() {
     // some code
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No, you need to call ngOnDestroy of the BaseClass explicitly (from the ChildClass). To do so, use the `super` reserved keyword (to get parent class reference) in the child component ngOnDestroy method.

`ngOnDestroy() {
    return super.ngOnDestroy();
}`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can try like this.

```
export class DerivedService extends MyBaseClass {
   // ...
   // here we are creating a object of our parent class
   parentClassRefObj = new MyBaseClass();
   constructor() {}
   // here is the function which is calling a parent class OnDestroy method
   myFun() {
      this.parentClassRefObj.OnDestroy();
   }
}

export class MyBaseClass implements OnDestroy {
   OnDestroy() {
     // some code
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the `ngOnDestroy` method defined in the base class will be called when the child class (the service) is destroyed:

```
@Injectable()
export class DerivedService extends MyBaseClass {
    // no ngOnDestroy method
}

@Injectable()
export abstract class MyBaseClass implements OnDestroy {
    public ngOnDestroy(): void {
        // some code
    }
}
```

Tested with Angular 17. I injected the service inside a component, and when the component is destroyed, the `ngOnDestroy` method of the service is also called by Angular.

Of course, if the service is injected in root (so, a singleton service), `ngOnDestroy` will only be called when the app is closed.